# Is there any way to make javascript setTimeout pause when I switch to another tab?

Tags: javascript

I am having some task that is executing, and when it finishes I show an animation and redirect the user to another page. I am using setTimeout method when redirecting to another page to wait for the whole animation to finish. However, if the user goes to another tab and the event that triggers the animation and redirection fires the user goes back to tab, but doesn't see the animation. Is there any way to tell the setTimeout method to wait until that tab is in active again?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can capture the timer id you get from `setTimeout` as well as the clock time you started that timer (e.g. using `Date.now()`), then call `clearTimeout` for that id when the document `blur` event triggers, recording what the remaining time should be based on the current time and the time you saved when you created the timeout, and when the document `focus` event triggers, start a new timeout with that remaining time as timeout value.

E.g. something like this (but obviously, you want to turn this into something better, with some administrative functions instead of inlining everything)

```js
const timerData = {
  interval: DEFAULT_INTERVAL,
  start: Date.now(),
  id: setTimout(..., DEFAULT_INTERVAL)
};

document.addEventListener(`blur`, () => {
  clearTimeout(timerData.id);
  timerData.remaining = timerData.start + timerData.interval - Date.now();
});

document.addEventListener(`focus`, () => {
  if (timerData.remaining) {
    timerData.interval = timerData.remaining
    timerData.remaining = undefined;
    timerData.start = Date.now();
    timerData.id = setTimeout(..., timerData.interval);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Timeout` class with a `start`/`stop` API. Then you can instantiate the class somewhere in your code, and after start or stop it based on user interface events.

**Class**

```
class Timeout {
  constructor(duration, callback) {
    this.duration = duration
    this.callback = callback
  }
  get timeout() { return this._timeout }
  set timeout(timeout) { this._timeout = timeout }
  get duration() { return this._duration }
  set duration(duration) { this._duration = duration }
  get callback() { return this._callback }
  set callback(callback) { this._callback = callback }
  start() {
    this.timeout = setTimeout(this.callback, this.duration)
    return this
  }
  stop() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout)
    return this
  }
}
```

**Instantiation**

```
let timeout = new Timeout(
  1000, 
  () => {
    console.log('timeout')
  }
)
```

**Start Timeout**

```
timeout.start()
```

**Stop Timeout**

```
timeout.stop()
```

Comment: Okay, but this doesn't answer the actual question, which is about pausing and then resuming a timeout, not just "stopping" one. Also your code seems peppered with underscores.